# Add quantum computing stackexchange to "What to ask here" page

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, help-center

In the help center on the page [What topics can I ask about here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there is a list of sister sites that might be better suited for some questions that are still on-topic here. I propose to add [quantum computing stackexchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) to this page. I'm only a silent visitor there, but it seems fairly active and certainly takes purely mathematical questions about quantum information, while I feel these kinds of questions stay unanswered quite often here (possibly due to the terminology and notation barrier).

Comment: I'm open to that idea, but it would improve your post to identify some posts on Math.SE that are germane to quantum computing.